# Images from cdn, and problems with SSL

Tags: asp.net, ssl, cdn

We have some images that are served up through a cdn (non ssl).  During checkout process our site switches to ssl, and now we're getting warnings because the page contains unsecure elements.

Besides getting SSL on the CDN or moving all images to the secure domain, are there any work arounds for this?

Is it possible to do some thing like 'mirror' the images or something like download them and then serve them as they're requested?

Using ASP.net mvc

Comment: Nope.  You cannot add security without somehow authenticating the remote party, which is what SSL does through PKI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best practice is to only load secure content in SSL.

Here are your options:

1. Get SSL on your CDN
2. Host your checkout-associated images somewhere with SSL (localhost or somewhere else)
3. Subvert your own SSL certificate

Option 3 is done by laundering the content from your CDN to the client using your webserver as an intermediary, using AJAX and a server-side script. Unfortunately there's no way to do that without adding a lot of HTTP requests and probably a forced delay on top of that (to make sure the images are stored before the client tries to load them).

That'll hurt your page load time pretty bad, and at that point you might as well just host the images on your webserver(s) since that's where they're being stored and loaded from at the end of your chain anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, there's no workaround. If any, it could be a severe security breach.

The best solution is to Enable SSL on the CDN, ideally with a URL that is compatible with the site's certificate.

the other alternatives, (copying files back, setting up a proxy-script) would obviously void all the benefits of the CDN.